# speed difference

Tags: android, memory, samsung-mobile

Are there a difference between access time of the built in memory and the SD cards?
if yes, what is it for both?
in computers environment the memory access time is measured in nano seconds while of hard disks in milliseconds, so preparing an application to load from memory rather than hard disk makes a greet difference. I want to know the situation in smart phones,

Answer (score 0):

Yes , There is a difference between the access time from Built-in memory and SD cards.

It is the Same reason as you have in Computer environment. Because , By default the access time for Built-in storage is faster than the External Storage. The reason for this is , the Internal storage is tightly tied with process for IO operation where it is not the case for External Storage. That's why you will have lesser access time for internal storage.

Comment: Thank you, but can you tell me some numbers or even a comparison e.g., the external is (twice) the internal, or the internal is 10 times faster, or what ever.

Comment: AFAIK 
There are different classes in SD cards , each one differs in their access speed. So , we can't say any ratio like you ask.